# C++ function return scope and reference

Tags: c++

recently I am learning C++ and have some doubt on the following case.

```
void function_a(const int &i){
  //using i to do something
}

int function_b(){
  return 1;
}
```

ok, if I am going to call...

```
function_a(function_b());
```

is there any chance that **function_a** read dirty reference from the it's param?

Thank for your time.

Comment: Temporaries last to the end of the full expression they are created in. The result of `function_b()` is a temporary, and it'll last until the end of the statement. (`function_a` can use it however it wants.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the compiler will generate an unnamed temporary value whose reference will be passed to `function_a`. Your code will be roughly equivalent to:

```
int temporary = function_b();
function_a(temporary);
```

The scope of `temporary` lasts until the end of the statement that calls `function_a()` (this is inconsequential for an integer, but may determine when a destructor is called for a more complex object).

Comment: Is that true? I always thought that `return 1` returns a left-hand constant that is immutable.

Comment: @Delan Azabani: The original question has been updated to include `const`.

Comment: @Delan Azabani: `int foo();` actually is an *rvalue* expression (r, not l)

Comment: Really? That's unexpected for me, but I guess we all learn something daily ;)

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no chance this will fail.  The temporary created by the return of `function_b` is guaranteed to remain in existence at least until the end of the statement.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write as below.

'i' cannot bind to a temporary returned from 'function_b'. There is no issue about a dirty reference here as a 'temporary' is involved here rather a reference to a function local (which goes out of scope once 'function_b' returns)

```
void function_a(int const &i){ 
  //using i to do something 
} 

int function_b(){ 
  return 1; 
}

int main(){
   function_a(function_b()); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reminder.
Is the temporary of the 'i' safe inside the scope of function_a ?

Comment: yes. the temporary is safe until the full expression

function_a(function_b());

Answer (score 0):

The question is moot.  That type of operation won't compile.

error C2664: 'function_a' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int' to 'int &'

Comment: I am sorry, I forget the const in the function_a param.